# Three.js breaks when trying to import OrbitControls.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

First I want to say that I'm very new to javascript and working with libraries. I'm trying to get some basic three.js code to work but it's not working and I'm not sure why. I have set up a basic scene using the Threejs.org documentation and I'm trying to get some basic orbit controls set up. Everything works fine until I try to import the orbit controls into my main script file. I then get an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I haven't tried much to solve my problem because I'm not even sure where to start. I've checked my spelling and made sure I had the correct relative path for my imports.

Here is the code that works:

```
import * as THREE from '/node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';

// import { OrbitControls } from '/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

// Construct basic scene elements
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    1,
    1000
);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
// const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

// Set parameters for scene elements
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

When I uncomment the second import for the orbit controls it breaks and gives me the error above. What is causing the error and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify why you are importing that way? With node modules you can usually import simply by referencing the name of the npm module like import whatever from “modulename”. Pretty rarely do you need to provide the path into node modules and a specific folder because node/Babel resolves that for you internally.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I've installed the module just like the documentation says and that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz or a code sandbox or similar that shows the issue you are facing?

Comment: The official documentation of `three.js` recommends nowhere to import the main library from `node_modules` like so: `import * as THREE from '/node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';`. For `npm` projects, it should be `import * as THREE from 'three';`. Besides, node workflows have to use a build tool like rollup in order to create an application bundle. Check out https://github.com/Mugen87/three-jsm for a minimal setup.

Comment: @Mugen87 If the main file is being referenced from a `<script type="module>`, then the use of a direct path is necessary because a browser can't resolve an `npm` package reference. I'll expand a little more in an answer.

Comment: Yes, but IMO it is still no good approach to import files from `node_modules` (meaning hosting the npm package on a web server). I think it's better to guide the OP towards a build tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You question seems to be missing some information, so I'm going to make some assumptions based on what you have provided. If any of my assumptions are incorrect, please update your question to provide further details.

My primary assumption is that you are using a `<script>` tag in your `HTML` to reference your main file, and that you are *not* using any JavaScript bundling tools like Mugen87 mentioned. If this is the case, then what you have is fine, ***BUT***, `OrbitControls` *will not work* unless you modify it.

If you dig into the `OrbitControls.js` file, you'll see (current as of r.130.1):

```js
import {
    EventDispatcher,
    MOUSE,
    Quaternion,
    Spherical,
    TOUCH,
    Vector2,
    Vector3
} from 'three';
```

The `from` reference makes the assumption that you are using the module from within an `npm` context, not a browser. Browsers don't know anything about `npm` packages, and they can't resolve `three` to its `node_modules` path, resulting in the error you saw. To make this work, you will need to modify the reference to point to the correct module path.

I personally don't like modifying the files inside `node_modules`, so I recommend the following:

1. Make a new folder called `vendor_mods/three/examples/jsm/controls` and copy `OrbitControls.js` into it.
2. Change the `from` reference in the copied file to point to `/node_modules/three/build/three.module.js`
3. Change the reference in your main file to point to your modified `OrbitControls.js`.

Now, the browser can reference all the pieces correctly, and everyone should be happy.

Comment: This works! Thank you. Are there any resources you know of to learn more about npm packages and bundlers? I'm sure you can tell I'm clearly a new developer and I have a lot to learn.

Comment: @user8083189 There are millions of tutorials on the web, and there is no single best resource. That is why StackOverflow closes questions asking for those kinds of suggestions. The only thing I would suggest is to search, search, search, and pay attention to when articles were published--there is nothing more frustrating than thinking you understand something, then finding out you were given old/obsolete information.

Answer (score 5):

Easy fix as of today:

change
`import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls';`
to
`import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';`

Source:

Three years ago was the last time [`three-orbitcontrols`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-orbitcontrols) was published. It is now deprecated with the following at the top of the page on npm:

> "Author's Message":
> three-js exposes real modules now via three/examples/jsm/... for example to import Orbit, do import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
import { OrbitControls } from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";